# Define the word 'smooth' in explict mathematical language?

Tags: math-history

Note in the comments of this question: [Create a formula that creates a curve between two points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695331/create-a-formula-that-creates-a-curve-between-two-points)
... that someone was asking me to define what is meant by the word "smooth".

Given that one of the answers was chosen as correct, are you able to define in what way the correct formula produces a "smooth" curve?

Comment: The word "smooth" means different things in different contexts, but a polynomial function is smooth by any reasonable definition of "smooth".

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582672/smoothest-function-which-passes-through-given-points/1589338#1589338

Comment: @littleO -- high degree polynomials often wiggle all over the place, so some people would not consider them to be smooth.

Comment: @bubba Ah, I suppose my statement was too strong.